# List all users in specific role

Tags: c#, lambda, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC I'm trying to get a list of all users in a specific role.
Fx. list of all users in role named "Admin":

```
var idsWithPermission = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin").Result;
var users = _db.ApplicationUser.Where(u => idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id)).ToListAsync();
return(users);
```

Compiler fails "u.Id" here: `idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id)`

> Error: Argument 1: Cannot convert from "string" to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser

This is a newbie questions, so might be very simple for a shark :-)
Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusersinroleasync?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: GetUsersInRoleAsync does not return List<string>, it returns Task<<List<TUser>>, so you need to resolve it first

Comment: Use Task.Wait() to complete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetUsersInRoleAsync` returns a list of `IdentityUser` objects. To get a list of IDs, you need to access the `Id` property of these objects.

```
// Get a list of users in the role
var usersWithPermission = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin").Result;

// Then get a list of the ids of these users
var idsWithPermission = usersWithPermission.Select(u => u.Id);

// Now get the users in our database with the same ids
var users = _db.ApplicationUser.Where(u => idsWithPermission.Contains(u.Id)).ToListAsync();

return users;
```

---

Note that using `.Result` on an `async` method is not advised, because it can lead to deadlocks. Instead use `await` and make your method `async`.

---

Also note that depending on your setup, if `ApplicationUser` inherits from `IdentityUser` and the identity system is correctly configured, `GetUsersInRoleAsync` will already return `ApplicationUser` objects and you only need to cast them to the correct type:

```
// Get a list of users in the role
var usersWithPermission = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin").Result;
var users = usersWithPermission.OfType<ApplicationUser>();

return users;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation - really appreciate your help.
I like the last suggestion, but I need to add a .Where clause to the expression, like: "u => u.UserName != "default_loader" && u.IsActive == true".

Is this possible with the last suggestion, or do you suggest I go with the first suggestion (which works by the way) :-)

Comment: You should be able to add Where after the call to OfType.Where do you hit a problem when trying to do that?

Comment: Hi again Nine.
A typo from me was the issue with the Where-clause :-)
It works like a charm!  Thank you very much...